# Table height is not working in react bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am using `react-bootstrap` components. I have a `table` covered by a `div`. The table has six rows. I have added `height` to my div, but `table` is not sized according to `height`.

**I need the table to fit inside the div, and the table header should be fixed and table body content should scroll.**

UI Looks like this below

[image]

It overflows in the div. I tried applying height and scroll. But it's not working.

Here's the Code I tried:

```
import Table from "react-bootstrap/Table";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: "200px", backgroundColor: "aqua" }}>
      <Table striped bordered>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Username</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody style={{ overflow:"scroll" }}>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I don't know how to make it. Please help me with some solutions.

Code SandBox Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-hamilton-qh1eh5?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the current CSS you have given, it should be fixed by placing an `overflow-y: scroll` to your container `div`. Since the styling is done as inline javascript, you must write it as `overflowY: "scroll"`.

EDIT: Since the actual question was about getting it fixed, you need to add `position: sticky` and `top:0` to the table header (and background color, otherwise it's transparent), and the previous `overflowY: scroll` should be `overflowY: auto` instead. Here is the result for that:

```js
import "./styles.css";
import Table from "react-bootstrap/Table";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        overflowY: "auto",
        height: "200px",
        backgroundColor: "green"
      }}
    >
      <Table striped bordered>
        <thead style={{ position: "sticky", top: 0, background: "green"  }}>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Username</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody
          style={{
            overflowY: "scroll",
            // height: "200px",
            backgroundColor: "aqua"
          }}
        >
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I added overflow-Y, it still not working. codesandbox link:  https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-hamilton-qh1eh5?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I have added a solution, it works on your CodePen.

Comment: Thanks. But I want the header to be fixed, only table content should scroll

Comment: This is an entirely different issue and should be informed in the post.

Comment: New edited answer above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249702/discussion-between-erecodes-and-bovop4).

Answer (score 0):

Here in documentation, https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/table/#always-responsive

> Across every breakpoint, use responsive for horizontally scrolling tables.

Have you tried adding `responsive` in `Table`?

```
import Table from "react-bootstrap/Table";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: "200px", backgroundColor: "aqua" }}>
      <Table responsive striped bordered>                    <--------
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Username</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        .....
      </Table>
   </div>
)}
```

Comment: Ya. I have added that. Its not working. Code sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-hamilton-qh1eh5?file=/src/App.js